# Smooch - How to access conversations with free plan and Web-Messenger widget

Tags: smooch

Just created a new account and integration with Web messenger widget on smooch.io. (So no direct API or similar, just the widget)

I can see messages coming in through the logs tab, like this:

[logs of incoming messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb3Js.png)

But maybe I am dumb or blind, but I can't figure out how or where to respond to these conversations...

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please provide information about what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to integrate with a system in order to intercept these messages. You can view available systems here: https://app.smooch.io/integrations

My company integrated the web messenger with slack. Every time someone writes via the web messenger, it shows up in slack.

Comment: Legend! Thanks. Just added slack and it works right out of the box.

Comment: @hackekacke No problem, happy to help :)